# literal_eval return invalid syntax when reading JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, xml, abstract-syntax-tree

While reading a JSON and trying to evaluate, a syntax error is returned.

json file has the below data

```
{
     "communication":{
        "xml":{
           "xmlData": "<test vers=\"1.0\" >random</test>",
           "user_id":"123456789"
        },
     },
}
```

Code snippet :

```
import ast
.
.
#json_file is the python obj which consists the data read from json file
.
val = ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(json_file))
print(val)
```

Error thrown :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ast.py", line 59, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ast.py", line 47, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, flags,
  File "<unknown>", line 4
    "xmlData": "<test vers="1.0" >random</test>",
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please suggest a way to resolve the syntax error. **Note that changing vers="1.0" to vers='1.0' would have fixed the issue but I do not have write access to this JSON file. My application is just reading the data.**

Comment: insted of loading directly the string to make a dictionary you can parse the string with a regex or brute force `data_str.replace('vers="1.0"', "vers='1.0'")`, you get a conflict with nested double quotes, then use `json.load`

Comment: xmlData in production will be dynamic. for eg: <test cal=\"5444$BCSD\" vers=\"1.0\" CTX=\"MHEBSNM\" >random</test>

Answer (score 1):

Your json is invalid, if you cant modify the file then modify the data in python.

corrected json

```json
{
     "communication":{
        "xml":{
           "xmlData":"<test vers=\"1.0\" >random</test>",
           "user_id":"123456789"
        }
     }
}
```

my code

```py
import json
import ast

fd = open("text.json")
json_file = json.load(fd)

val = ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(json_file))
print(val)
```

output

```json
{'communication': {'xml': {'xmlData': '<test vers="1.0" >random</test>', 'user_id': '123456789'}}}
```